# Does this exist: HTML Template Renderer Written in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django-templates

What of instead of the standard Django template rendering model which is server side, there were a library that allowed something that looked like a Django template to be rendered with JavaScript in the client's browser? The variables could be filled in by getting a JSON blob from the server and rendering the template would be done entirely on the client side.

Does a library like this already exist?

As I understand it, [GWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) sort of does this, but behind the scenes and with *a ton* of programmer overhead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What javascript templating engine do you recommend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend)

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I think this is a duplicate. Also, thanks to everyone that answered.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be thinking of the [recently announced](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/04/new-official-jquery-plugins-provide-templating-data-linking-and-globalization/) jQuery [template plugins](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).  There are of course other solutions out there, this has gotten the most press lately, with a similar syntax to what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Google Closure has a [template library](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/), there is [TrimPath](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates), and there is a [long list of answers over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend).

Answer (score 0):

you probably think of [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), but you can also check [pure templates](http://niczsoft.com/tag/pure)